# A Silly confusion about limits

Tags: calculus, limits

**This is just a clarification about a question. My initial working of this question might be wrong. Please help me check**

> *Question* : Show that $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}} - 1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}} + 1}}$ does not exist.

It is definitely clear that the left hand limit equals -1. 
For the right hand, $\lim_{x \to 0^+}{\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}} - 1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}} + 1}}$ = $\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{e^{\frac{1}{h}} - 1}{e^{\frac{1}{h}} + 1}}$. 
 
Directly, substituting $ x = 0$ we get the limit as $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ which does not exit.

*The above was my own thoughts which might be wrong.*

But the limit can also be transformed into 
$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1 - \frac{1}{e^{1/h}}}{1 + \frac{1}{e^{1/h}}} = 1$.

So my confusion is howcome when the right hand limit is not transformed it does not exist. But when transformed it exists as 1.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90901/discussion-on-question-by-rash-a-silly-confusion-about-limits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $x\to0^{-}$, $\frac{1}{x}\to -\infty$:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}e^{\frac{1}{x}}=e^{-\infty}=\frac{1}{e^{\infty}}=0$$
Therefore, the left-hand limit is:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}{\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}} - 1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}} + 1}}=
\frac{0-1}{0+1}=-1$$

---

As $x\to0^{+}$, $\frac{1}{x}\to\infty$:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}e^{\frac{1}{x}}=e^{\infty}=\infty$$
Therefore, the right-hand limit is:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}{\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}} - 1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}} + 1}}=
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}{\frac{1 - \frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}}{1 + \frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}}}=
\frac{1 - \frac{1}{\infty}}{1 + \frac{1}{\infty}}=\frac{1-0}{1+0}=\frac{1}{1}=1
$$

---

Since the two one-sided limits are not equal, the limit itself does not exist:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}{\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}} - 1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}} + 1}}\ne
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}{\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}} - 1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}} + 1}}\implies
\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}} - 1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}} + 1}}=DNE
$$

Comment: What do you have to say about the OP saying "$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1 - \frac{1}{e^{1/h}}}{1 + \frac{1}{e^{1/h}}} = 1$" ?

Comment: All I can say is that I'm not sure how the OP got from $x\to 0^{+}$ to $h\to 0$

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: The limit does not exist because when you approach it from the left, it equals $-1$, but when you approach it from the right, it equals $1$. By definition, a two-sided limit does not exist when the two one-sided limits are not equal.

Comment: Not sure if I completely understood your question though, so apologies if I have misunderstood

Comment: U did not question. I aldready know that a limit does not exist when LHL & RHL  are not same. My question why before transformation it was $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ and after that it was 1.

Comment: I think the confusion arises from the fact that you simply plugged in $x=0$, which we cannot do since it is undefined, we are only allowed to evaluate $\frac{1}{x}$ as a limit, and then $x$ never actually becomes zero. Nothing changes in the expression after you rewrite it, it is just easier to evaluate the limit correctly when written in that way.

Comment: Thomas Fjærvik, I think you have to tag like this: @rash . Otherwise, rash might not get notified.